# SQL Pivot without Aggregation - duplicate entries

Tags: sql, pivot

I have the following table structure

```
Create Table PivotTabSample (
    ID INT IDENTITY(100000001,1) NOT NULL,
    Product Nvarchar(30),
    StoreNumber INT,
    StoreSalesEstimate DECIMAL,
    StoreSalesActual DECIMAL
)
```

The sample values are populated with the following insert -

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[PivotTabSample]
    ([Product],[StoreNumber],[StoreSalesEstimate],[StoreSalesActual])
 VALUES ('P0001','101',500,450)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[PivotTabSample]
    ([Product],[StoreNumber],[StoreSalesEstimate],[StoreSalesActual])
 VALUES ('P0002','101',300,350)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[PivotTabSample]
    ([Product],[StoreNumber],[StoreSalesEstimate],[StoreSalesActual])
 VALUES ('P0003','101',50,61)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[PivotTabSample]
    ([Product],[StoreNumber],[StoreSalesEstimate],[StoreSalesActual])
 VALUES ('P0004','101',100,900)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[PivotTabSample]
    ([Product],[StoreNumber],[StoreSalesEstimate],[StoreSalesActual])
 VALUES ('P0005','101',10,9)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[PivotTabSample]
    ([Product],[StoreNumber],[StoreSalesEstimate],[StoreSalesActual])
 VALUES ('P0001','102',1500,1450)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[PivotTabSample]
    ([Product],[StoreNumber],[StoreSalesEstimate],[StoreSalesActual])
 VALUES ('P0002','102',1400,3500)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[PivotTabSample]
    ([Product],[StoreNumber],[StoreSalesEstimate],[StoreSalesActual])
 VALUES ('P0003','102',150,610)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[PivotTabSample]
    ([Product],[StoreNumber],[StoreSalesEstimate],[StoreSalesActual])
 VALUES ('P0004','102',800,900)
```

I am trying to do a PIVOT on this data set. and I run the following query -

```
SELECT Product, [101], [102]
FROM PivotTabSample 
PIVOT
(   min(StoreSalesActual) 
    FOR StoreNumber IN ([101],[102])
)AS p
```

The result that is get is not desired manner - I do not get in one the Product and Store details. There are two Product rows for each Store.
I do not want that. There is no aggregation required here, but I am not sure how to achieve it.

I would like to have the results like this -

```
Product   101ActualSales 101EstimatedSales 102ActualSales 102estimatedSales
P001      100              101                90            91
P002      
P003      
P001
```

Please advise.

Comment: Yeah.  `PIVOT` is confusing.  Extra columns in the table result in unexpected rows in the result set.  That's why almost all examples have a subquery in the `FROM` clause, restricting the columns only to those actually used in the query.

Comment: Your desired results are in the same format/structure as your input data, just with different column names...

Comment: Extremely Sorry. that was a wrong representation of expected results. I have updated the expected results

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (SQL Server?)

Comment: SQL server 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH CTE
AS (SELECT Product,
           ISNULL([101], 0) AS '101ActualSales',
           ISNULL([102], 0) AS '102ActualSales',
           0 AS '101EstimatedSales',
           0 AS '102EstimatedSales'
    FROM PivotTabSample
        PIVOT
        (
            SUM(StoreSalesActual)
            FOR StoreNumber IN ([101], [102])
        ) AS p)
SELECT product,
       SUM([101ActualSales]) AS [101actualsales],
       SUM([101EstimatedSales]) AS [101EstimateSales],
       SUM([102ActualSales]) AS [102actualsales],
       SUM([102EstimatedSales]) AS [102EstimateSales]
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM CTE
    UNION
    SELECT pt.Product,
           0 AS '101ActualSales',
           0 AS '102ActualSales',
           ISNULL([101], 0) AS '101EstimateSales',
           ISNULL([102], 0) AS '102EstimateSales'
    FROM PivotTabSample
        PIVOT
        (
            SUM(StoreSalesEstimate)
            FOR StoreNumber IN ([101], [102])
        ) AS pt
) AS x
GROUP BY product;
```

http://rextester.com/GFID38296

Comment: @Sabyasachi Mukherjee Please see my edit for your updated format

Answer (score 0):

Having just had a similar problem at work where I've had to modify a pivot that had the same output as yours, I've found that wrapping into a CTE helped.  I just need to figure out why, but I suspect adding the **StoreSalesActual** has helped...

```
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT Product, 
StoreNumber,
StoreSalesActual
FROM #PivotTabSample
)
SELECT DISTINCT Product, [101], [102]
FROM cte
PIVOT
(   
MAX(StoreSalesActual) 
FOR StoreNumber IN ([101],[102])
)AS p
GROUP BY Product, [101], [102]
```

Comment: The required output data has Actual columns and Estimated columns.  This answer only gives Actual columns....

Comment: @MattBailie - I know, the original question was edited while I was posting - I'm back doing my "work" now.